# How to move an item from one list into another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists:

```
x = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

and

```
y = []
```

How do I move any of the items from list `x` into list `y`?

Answer (score 4):

```
y.append(x.pop(0))
y.append(x.pop(1))
y.append(x.pop(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since OP isn't clear on how "any" items is defined, this method assumes you are given a set of items you want to move:

```
x = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
y = []

movers = {'Two', 'Four', 'Five'}

for i, j in enumerate(x):
    if j in movers:
        y.append(x.pop(i))

(x, y)  # (['One', 'Three', 'Five'], ['Two', 'Four'])
```